# Using Nested Recycler Views with Android Paging Library

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I am trying to use the android paging library to display a feed of images. Each image can contain many comments and can be filtered with various parameters.

Currently, I am using a ViewModel inside of the PhotoAdapter to submit a filtered list of comments to the CommentAdapter for each item in the PhotoAdapter.

Although I believe having a reference to a ViewModel inside of an adapter is prone to memory leaks and defeats the purpose of the ViewModel.

In fragment:

```
photosViewModel.getPhotosLiveData().data().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), (photoIds) -> {
        photoAdapter.submitList(photoIds);
});
```

In PhotoAdapter:

```
public class PhotoAdapter extends PagedListAdapter<String, PhotoAdapter.PhotoViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    MyViewModel myViewModel; //Storing View model in adapter is a bad idea
    CommentsViewModel commentsViewModel;

             .....boilerplate code.....

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PhotoViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String photoId = getItem(position);
        holder.setupAdapter(photoId);
    }


    public class PhotoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private RecyclerView commentRecyclerView;
        private CommentRecyclerAdapter commentAdapter;

        private void setupAdapter(String photoId){
            myViewModel.getMe().observe(context, me ->{
                FilterQuery filterQuery = new FilterQuery(photoId, me.getLocation(), me.getPreferences());
                CommentsSearchResult result = commentsViewModel.getCommentsLiveData(filterQuery);
                result.comments.observe(context, (PagedList<Comment> items) -> {
                    commentAdapter.submitList(items);
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This method 'works' but what is the proper way to implement such a pattern that is not prone to leaks and utilizes ViewModels correctly?

Comment: did you find solution? im trying to implement the same...